# Force a module to initialize with runtimeChunk: 'single'

Tags: jquery, webpack

Is there a way force a module to initialize again when using `runtimeChunk: 'single'` ?

**Context**: I have a legacy app where js is included with script tags (globals everywhere), trying to migrate to webpack. I need `runtimeChunk: 'single'` for jQuery and it's plugins (have one instance of jQuery with all the plugins attached to it, instead of multiple jQuery instances).

But then my app has a lot of places where buttons trigger ajax requests fetching HTML containing an entrypoint. For instance a modal has an entrypoint that should be executed every time the modal is fetched.

Except that the modal entrypoint gets executed only once with `runtimeChunk: 'single'`.

Is there a workaround for this situation ?

**Edit**: I removed the `runtimeChunk: 'single'` and moved jQuery to be global (using a script tag). But now I face a problem where I include a file from different files, but I want it to be executed only once (file instantiates a class like follow: `const ged = new GED(params, anotherParam);`). How do I go about this ?

Answer (score 0):

I will answer myself with my progress.

I ended up removing `runtimeChunk: single`, moving jQuery dependency to a script tag (was in webpack with my previous attempt).

And for files that initialize multiple times, I installed [awilix](https://github.com/jeffijoe/awilix) which is a service container, and set the object I wanted to be instantiated once to be registered as a singleton.